a pullback in manifolds - an example
I have one more question on the book: Nakahara:Geometry, Topology and physics
How was derived the 3rd term in $f_{\ast}V$:
$$-(a\frac{y^1}{y^3}+b\frac{y^2}{y^3})\frac{\partial}{\partial y^3}$$
?
I understand that $\mu\in\{1,2\}$ and $\alpha\in\{1,2,3\}.$


You are intersted in the component along $y^3$. Let us apply the definition of $f_*$ to your vector field in the case where the function acted upon is $g=y^3$. It says $$(f_*V)(y^3)=V(y^3\circ f)=V(\sqrt{1-(x^1)^2-(x^2)^2}).$$ Now derive and express it in terms of the $(y)$-coordinates. For example, we have
$$a\partial_{x^1}(\sqrt{1-(x^1)^2-(x^2)^2})=a\frac{-x^1}{\sqrt{1-(x^1)^2-(x^2)^2}}=-a\frac{y^1}{y^3}.$$
I am sure you can work out the other term!

Thank you. You mean $\partial_{x^1}$ right ?

Yes! Nice catch, edited.
